# Sum the first N numbers in java

Tags: java

> Hello, I am new to programming and I am trying to write a small program where it will calculate the sum for first N numbers. The problem is it does not work for even numbers. I have not managed to figure out why. 
>   My code is as follow:

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int sum = (1+n)/2*n;
    System.out.println(sum + " is the sum of first " + n + " numbers");
```

Comment: @RohitJain Actually it gives 8 for n=4, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work for even n because `(n+1)/2` is truncated to an int.

This means that if, for example, `n=4`, `(n+1)/2` results in 2 instead of 2.5, so when you multiply it by n, you get 8 instead of the desired 10.

You can overcome this problem simply by changing the order of the operations. If you first multiply n by (n+1), the result is guaranteed to be even, so dividing it by 2 will produce the correct answer.

```
int sum = n*(1+n)/2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have integer division with `(1+n)/2`.  If your number is even, then `(1+n)` is odd and the division by `2` will truncate any decimal result, so that an `int` divided by an `int` is still an `int`.

Multiply by `n` first, then divide by `2`.  This ensures that the product is even before dividing, so the result is correct.

```
int sum = (1+n) * n / 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

One can use `((n * (n + 1)) / 2)`. But I think the following will work without overflow errors for a few additional values of `n`:

```
if ((n & 1) == 0) {
  sum = ((n >> 1) * (n + 1));
} else {
  sum = (n * ((n + 1) >> 1));
}
```